# Swimlane/datatable throws error on compilation time. Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: typescript, datatable

I'm using swimlane/datatable, https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/components/datatable.component.ts with typescript 2.6, Angular5.

When TS try to transpile, it throws ngx-datatable/src/components/datatable.component.ts(686,22): [91merror[0m TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type '{}'.

Could anybody know what is this about?

The error is in the line .push(item):

```
 const map = new Map();
 originalArray.forEach((item: any) => {
  const key = item[groupBy];
  if (!map.has(key)) {
     map.set(key, [item]);
  } else {
     map.get(key).push(item);
  }
  i++;
 });
```

Comment: Hmm, [I can't reproduce this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As far as I see, the [`map` constant](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/components/datatable.component.ts#L678) should be of type `Map<any, any>`, which means that `map.get(key)` should be of type `any`, which means that `map.get(key).push(item)` should *not* be an error.  Somehow in your compilation `map` must be of a different type (like `Map<{},{}>` or something).  Have you done something like override the declaration for the global/ambient `Map` value or the `MapConstructor` type?

Comment: @jcalz I've just updated the code adding the map declaration.This file is not a good practice to edit, since is the one that came with datatable library.

Comment: I don't want you to edit it; I asked if you have a custom definition for the [`Map` constructor value](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L36), or the [`MapConstructor` type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L31) somewhere in your code.  If you are not using the [ES2015 collections definitions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts) or have [modified](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) them, it could be causing this.

Comment: The problem maybe is that my target is ES5? Since ES2015 is ES6.

Comment: The `target` is fine (although you will need [a `Map` polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections) at runtime if you are really targeting an es5 environment without `Map`)... but what's your `--lib`?

Comment: My lib is "lib": [ "es5", "dom" ]

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.  If I do that I get an error on the line `const map = new Map();` because `es5` doesn't know about `Map` at all.  Are you sure you don't get that error first?  I wonder where you have `Map` defined.   I think you probably want at least `es2015` in your `lib` instead of `es5` since the datatable code depends on it.

Comment: The thing is that if I change to es2015, my project starts to give me multiples errors, because currently I'm using @tpyes/core-js. So is a mess, but I will try to update all this, removing polyfills to see how it works. Thank you!